Compile Error: Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'Value' ('Int' vs. 'String')
I wrote a Parameter enum, where the some case accepts a RequestParameter type, which can be a custom object or a dictionary. The dictionary is used to generate queryItems. However, I'm encountering an error when using a dictionary:
public enum Parameter {
  case some(RequestParameter)
  case none
}

public extension Parameter {
  var queryItems: [URLQueryItem]? {
    guard case let .some(this) = self else {
      return nil
    }
    return this.queryItems
  }

  var encodable: Encodable? {
    guard case let .some(this) = self else {
      return nil
    }
    return this
  }
}

public protocol RequestParameter: Encodable {
  var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] { get }
}

public extension RequestParameter {
  var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {
    var this = [URLQueryItem]()
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    for child in mirror.children {
      guard let label = child.label, let value = child.value as? CustomStringConvertible else {
        continue
      }
      this.append(.init(name: label, value: value.description))
    }
    return this
  }
}

extension Dictionary: RequestParameter where Key == String, Value: CustomStringConvertible & Encodable {
  public var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {
    var this = [URLQueryItem]()
    for (key, value) in self {
      this.append(.init(name: key, value: value.description))
    }
    return this
  }
}

let p = Parameter.some([
  "string": "foo",
  "integer": -1,
])


Conflicting arguments to generic parameter 'Value' ('Int' vs. 'String')
The Value type of the dictionary is constrained to CustomStringConvertible & Encodable. Why can't the dictionary have different types for Value (e.g., Int and String)? How can I solve this issue?


Do you realise you wrote where Key == String, Value == String?

According  your extension, a Dictionary conforms to RequestParameter  when Key == String, and Value == String.  You might solve the issue by making type Value an enum (which has cases for all values you need), or define a protocol MyValueProtocol and corresponding types, respectively extensions to existing types.

My bad, the example code in my question was mistakenly written. The correct version should be Value: CustomStringConvertible & Encodable. I have updated the question and would appreciate further assistance. Thanks.

While searching for a solution, I found a similar question that seems related to Multiple Dispatch, but I still don’t know how to resolve my problem. Any advice?

Why Parameter instead of using Optional<RequestParameter>? Why require RequestParameter to be Encodable? Note that "using CustomStringConvertible as a generic constraint is discouraged" per Apple. Seems like the Mirror stuff is so you can just conform a type and it'll give a default implementation; how about making a custom Encoder and just using Encodable instead?

You can modify the Dictionary extension to support any type that conforms to CustomStringConvertible:
extension Dictionary: RequestParameter where Key == String, Value: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {
        var this = [URLQueryItem]()
        for (key, value) in self {
            this.append(.init(name: key, value: value.description))
        }
        return this
    }
}


My bad, the example code in my question was mistakenly written. The correct version should be Value: CustomStringConvertible & Encodable. I have updated the question and would appreciate further assistance. Thanks.

My understanding is that when you write:
extension Dictionary: RequestParameter where Key == String, Value: CustomStringConvertible & Encodable {

you are Constraining Value to one type at a time conforming to CustomStringConvertible & Encodable
that is why :
let p = Parameter.some([
    "string": "foo",
])

and
let p = Parameter.some([
    "integer": -1,
])

work fine.
Swift usually don't like "Heterogenous collections" very much, since you need to pass a string to the URLQueryItem initializer you could map the values of your dictionary, eg.:
let p = Parameter.some([
    "string": "foo",
    "integer": -1,
].mapValues(String.init(describing:)))

